# I can't install or remove anything on Ubuntu 16.04, and virtually nothing on login page

Tags: apt, login

First off, sorry for my bad English(I'm foreigner...) and I'm relatively new to using Ubuntu, so I might be asking too easy question.

On Friday, I tried to update my Ubuntu 16.04 as usual and it was stuck in middle because the internet dropped, [though I can't remember clearly where it was stuck at because I was busy with something else.]so I just closed it with force.

At first there seemed to be nothing wrong, but when I went through tty1 to see if something was wrong, there was no login as usual, but strings of endless error messages that went too fast to see what was going on.
Then I decided to backup my notebook just to be safe, but this time, it was stuck when it was recovering `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0.4`
Then it was turned off, and from that moment, whenever I turn on my lab top, instead of usual login page, there is only black page, frozen with only quotes...

```
dev/sda11: clean, 380596/6144000 files, 6277962/24551936 blocks
```

That's problem no.1 and the another major problem is when I go through tty1 and try to fix the problem with installing or removing, it doesn't work at all.
Instead, whenever I write any command that has do with "apt" same messages appear.

```
apt: error while loading shared libraries: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0: file too short
```

And when I wrote sudo ldconfig to see if there's any hint, this was the return.

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real: File /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 is empty, not checked.
/sbin/ldconfig.real: File /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1 is empty, not checked.
/sbin/ldconfig.real: File /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0.4 is empty, not checked.
/sbin/ldconfig.real: File /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so is empty, not checked.
```

In short, there is no login page and `apt-get` is not working at all. I didn't made any single progress since Friday, I've tried everything and nothing happened.

Comment: boot live medium and check the partition using gparted